# Communication between two ASP.NET Core projects in the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two ASP.Net core projects in the same solution. Both of these will be deployed on the same server at different ports (since they serve different applications). What's the best way for these two API projects to communicate with each other? For example, if an API is called on one of the projects and it wants to notify the other project, what's the best (fast and secure) option to do so?

[image]

- Should these two projects expose internal APIs exclusively for talking to each other? (In such case how can these internal APIs stay internal and secure)
- Use a message broker?
- Some other option

Comment: Can't you just add reference and access methods directly if they in same solution?

Comment: Otherwise could  just use the external ports with api key and https

Comment: Try to improve your question by providing more context about what *fast* and *secure* means here. Otherwise the question is just too broad.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I'm concerned that if I create APIs for internal communication only, it may be exposed to the public (or even worse exposed to the public in HTTP). As for speed, I'm just concerned that there MIGHT be more efficient ways of doing this that are equally or less complex. I don't have a particular performance goal in mind.

Comment: @JimmyShoe already tried the adding reference method, didn't work for me. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use 2 types of communications.

1. HTTP for sync, when I need an immediate answer from another service.
2. For async, mostly message broker. To send a message and the other service(s) process that. There are more async solutions depend on your needs.

Balazs